# Problem passing column name to sapply within a function

Tags: r, function, sapply

I need to calculate a lot of predicted probabilities for multiple logit models, and I'm trying to write a function to speed up the process. I'm having trouble making my function work correctly, however. The problem seems to be the "iv=x" portion of the code below. I'm not sure how to correctly pass the column name there.

```
pp <- function(iv, model, df) {
  lev <- levels(df[[iv]])
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
  mean(predict(model, type = "response", 
               newdata = mutate(df, iv = x)), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
  l.prob
}


test <- pp(iv="myvar", model=model1, df=mydf)
test
```

Here is some example data showing how the function isn't working:

```
set.seed(123123)
df=data.frame(y=sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100), x1=as.factor(rep(c("value1", "value2"), 50)), x2=rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=10))


logit1 <- glm(y ~ x1+x2, data = df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(logit1)


#what the predicted probabilities should be (0.4173400, 0.4625565)
lev <- levels(df$x1)
pp <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
  mean(predict(logit1, type = "response", 
               newdata = mutate(df, x1 = x)), na.rm=TRUE)
})
pp

#now running function (produces probabilities 0.44 and 0.44)

pp <- function(iv, model, df) {
  lev <- levels(df[[iv]])
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
    mean(predict(model, type = "response", 
                 newdata = mutate(df, iv = x)), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
  l.prob
}


test <- pp(iv="x1", model=logit1, df=df)
test
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data? Also your call to `glm()` for the logit model would be helpful to reproduce your work. You can share your data by pasting the output of `dput(mydf)` into a code chunk in your question.

Comment: the problem is it isn't passing that column name to the function, the results are the same as if I put in a nonsense name for the variable instead of "iv". The predicted probabilities are identical.

Comment: Okay, edited with some example data.

Comment: (1) please use `set.seed()` so outcome values stay the same. right now they change; (2) can you describe exactly what you think should be happening with your iteration over the levels of `df$x1`?

Comment: Whoops sorry about that, updated. I believe it should be calculating the mean probability of a 1 outcome for each level of x1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider dynamically assigning column before prediction using `[[` and avoid `mutate` (especially if it is the only method used in `dplyr` and can save you a `library` call).

```r
pp <- function(iv, model, df) {
  lev <- levels(df[[iv]])
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
        df[[iv]] <- x
        mean(predict(model, type = "response", newdata = df), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
}
```

Another base R method is to add new column with a temp name and then rename all columns with dynamic parameter.

```r
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
        mean(predict(model, type = "response", 
                     newdata = setNames(transform(df, tmp = x), c(colnames(df), iv)), 
             na.rm=TRUE)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to mimic the assignment in the original `pp`: `x1 = x`.  Right now you're trying to use `iv` inside `sapply`, but within `sapply` your function is only referring to `x`.

Making this update reproduces the outcome of `pp` with `test`:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1L)

# hard-coded df$x1
lev <- levels(df$x1)
pp <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
  mean(predict(logit1, type = "response", 
               newdata = mutate(df, x1 = x)), na.rm=TRUE)
})
pp
   value1    value2 
0.4799503 0.5400409 


# 'x1' passed in as :iv: arg
pp <- function(iv, model, df) {
  lev <- levels(df[[iv]])
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
    mean(predict(model, type = "response", 
                 newdata = mutate(df, x1 = x)), na.rm=TRUE) 
  })
  l.prob
}

test <- pp(iv="x1", model=logit1, df=df)

test
   value1    value2 
0.4799503 0.5400409
```

As an alternative, you can pass in `x1` directly, unquoted, to `pp()`, and use `{{ }}` ([curly curly notation](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-)) to evaluate `iv` in `df`:

```r
pp <- function(iv, model, df) {
  lev <- levels(df %>% pull({{iv}})) # <-- use {{ }}
  l.prob <- sapply(lev, FUN=function(x){
    mean(predict(model, type = "response", 
                 newdata = mutate(df, x1 = x)), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
  l.prob
}


test <- pp(iv=x1, model=logit1, df=df) # <-- x1 has no quotes
test
   value1    value2 
0.4799503 0.5400409
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without using the variable name (x1) in the function? I want to be able to do this for any variable.